# While loop Vectorization

Tags: matlab, while-loop, vectorization

I would like to know if there is some way to vectorize this code. I tried so hard to do it... but failed.

```
while (delta_F > e) && (i < maxLoop)      
    x1 = x0+d;
    y0 = f(x0);
    y1 = f(x1);
    if y1 < y0
        x0= x1;
        d = a*d;
    else
        vF = [vF;x1];
        d = -b*d;
    end
    i = i + 1;
    if length(vF) > 1
        ultm = vF(end);
        pultm = vF(end-1);
        delta_F = abs(ultm+pultm)/2;
    end
end
```

It's a simple implementation of the Rosenbrock method for finding the min of a function.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what the loop is supposed to do - can you write it as a formula? Furthermore: What are the initialization values of all those variables?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Matlab's vectorization works over fixed-size arrays/matrices. If you want to speed up this code in some other ways, the single biggest thing you could do is reuse your previous results in each iteration of the loop and get rid of the extraneous variables.

```
y0 = f(x0);
while (delta_F > e) && (i < maxLoop)
    x1 = x0+d;
    y1 = f(x1);
    if (y1 < y0) %# new starting point, so swap points
        x0 = x1;
        y0 = y1; 
        d = a*d;
    else         %# same starting point, refine step and see if we're done
        d = -b*d;
        delta_F = abs(x1-x0)/2;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

This removes half the calls to `f` and the dynamic resizing of `vF`, which is horrendously slow, especially as `vF` gets big.

Comment: I didn't look close enough to see if this produces the same result as the original code, but +1 for getting rid of dynamic resizing and the resulting quadratic time penalty!