# Problems approaching Rosenbrock method

Tags: matlab, math

So I have an assigment where I have to do some... fighting with the code so I can further understand how does it work/what are good parameters for the method. About everything I found in the web is about rosenbrock function, and I am now almost sure it's a different thing from rosenbrock method.

I found this question from a while ago, and it's quite similar to what I was trying (without much success)

[While loop Vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283995/while-loop-vectorization)

The code I have so far is something like:

```
function [T] = rosenbrock(f,xx0,maxLoop,error,d,a,b)
delta_F=10;
x0=xx0;
y0 = f(x0);
i=0;
vF=[];

while (delta_F > error) && (i < maxLoop)      
x1 = x0+d;
y0 = f(x0);
y1 = f(x1);
if y1 < y0
    x0= x1;
    d = a*d;
else
    vF = [vF;x1];
    d = -b*d;
end
i = i + 1;
if length(vF) > 1
    ultm = vF(end);
    pultm = vF(end-1);
    delta_F = abs(ultm+pultm)/2;
end
end

T=vF;
```

And I call it from another script with this:

```
x0=1;
error=1e-3;
maxLoop=500;
fun=@(x)(sin(x)); 
[S]=rosenbrock(fun, x0, maxLoop,error,1,2,-1.5)
```

And it's giving me absurd numbers like 10^88 and such. And part of the problem is I don't really know how I should approach the problem, I find the amount of theory given to us small and don't really know how to differentiate good results from bad ones

and even if I get... something with the method (so far the idea was to store the points used so later I could do something with them), but I also am not sure about what to do them, like, plotting into the function, that short of thing.

Point is, code does not work, I do not understand why because as far as I know it's doing what is supposed to do, and don't really know what to do next. I can explain further but it'd be with my own words since the wikipedia has a poor article and as I said everything else is about rosenbrock function, which seems similar but not quite the same.

Comment: I don't understand.  What are you wanting the code to do?  Why is 10^88 absurd?

Comment: @Teepeemm The code has to find a minimum inside a given function. I believe it's absurd to get such a number because the function passed in this case (I've used others too) is a sen(x) function, so... minimum at that place... yeah it might be. But I start at x0=1. So I find little sense in it

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered two mistakes in your code (in the code you copied):

1. You want to calculate the stepwidth named delta_F. "Delta's" are always calculated as a difference of two values:

   ```
   delta_F = abs(ultm-pultm)/2;
   ```
2. Your function-call is wrong. Replace the "b"-value with 0.5 instead of -1.5.